# ng2-charts tooltip and legend stopped working

Tags: chart.js, ng2-charts

The chart has been working fine, but suddenly it isn't anymore. 
[Here's a demonstration of the problem.](https://i.gyazo.com/aa7484236549589ec256a77f0e5fe188.mp4/)

As you can see, the tooltips are transparent and flickering, and they don't move to the next point I'm hovering over. Also, the legend doesn't turn the lines on/off when I click on their labels.

Here are my options:

```
export const LineChartLevel3Options = {
lineChartLabels: ["Tid1", "Tid2", "Tid3", "Tid4"],
lineChartOptions: {
responsive: false,
title: {
  display: true,
  text: 'Graf over vitale værdier',
  fontColor: 'black',
  fontSize: 20,
},
legend: {
  labels: {
    fontColor: '#CCC'
  }
},
scales: {
  yAxes: [{
    ticks: {
      fontColor: '#CCC'
    },
    gridLines: {
      color: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 1)'
    }
  }],
  xAxes: [{
    ticks: {
      fontColor: '#CCC'
    },
    gridLines: {
      color: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 1)'
    }
  }],
}


},
  lineChartColors: [
    { // grey
      backgroundColor: 'rgba(255,0,0,0.3)',
      borderColor: 'rgba(148,159,177,1)',
      pointBackgroundColor: 'rgba(148,159,177,1)',
      pointBorderColor: '#fff',
      pointHoverBackgroundColor: '#fff',
      pointHoverBorderColor: 'rgba(148,159,177,0.8)'
    },
    { // dark grey
      backgroundColor: 'rgba(77,83,96,0.2)',
      borderColor: 'rgba(77,83,96,1)',
      pointBackgroundColor: 'rgba(77,83,96,1)',
      pointBorderColor: '#fff',
      pointHoverBackgroundColor: '#fff',
      pointHoverBorderColor: 'rgba(77,83,96,1)'
    },
    { // grey
      backgroundColor: 'rgba(148,159,177,0.2)',
      borderColor: 'rgba(148,159,177,1)',
      pointBackgroundColor: 'rgba(148,159,177,1)',
      pointBorderColor: '#fff',
      pointHoverBackgroundColor: '#fff',
      pointHoverBorderColor: 'rgba(148,159,177,0.8)'
    }
  ],
  lineChartLegend: true,
  lineChartType: 'line',
};
```

And the HTML:

```
<canvas baseChart width="650" height="250" [datasets]="getJoinedChartData(patientService.patientLevel3)" [labels]="lineChart3.lineChartLabels" [options]="lineChart3.lineChartOptions"
        [colors]="lineChart3.lineChartColors" [legend]="lineChart3.lineChartLegend" [chartType]="lineChart3.lineChartType">
      </canvas>
```

EDIT: It seems like it has something to do with my datasets and labels. I copied the line chart from valor-software's website and it worked until I used my own labels and datasets with that one. Still haven't figured out what's wrong with them.

Comment: In your Options, try adding a tooltips object: `lineChartOptions: { responsive: true, tooltips: { mode: 'index', intersect: false } }`. You can see all the tooltip options [here](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/configuration/tooltip.html)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It turned out that binding the `dataset` of the chart to a method is a bad idea. The `getJoinedChartData()` method took some data of one of the patient objects of my application and returned it as an array that could be used with the chart. Instead I created a variable in my component and assigned the array to that, then bound the `dataset` to that variable. Everything is fine now.

Comment: Yes, I can confirm this behavior. I was using a `getter` for getting the `datasets`, the tooltips didn't show up either. Setting it on a class property also fixed this issue for me.

Comment: +1; I had ```data``` bound to a getter too and not only were the tooltips not showing, but the CPU usage was also getting high. Changed the binding to a property -> both problems fixed